# Extjs form setting a value

Tags: forms, extjs

I set the date value through the Extjs value form property, but the function to clear the field does not appear in the field itself, which is present when setting the value from the calendar. What should be done?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDnYS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOel4.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which version of extjs are you trying?

if you are using  extjs 6.2

Then are you looking for triggers in form?
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html#cfg-triggers

Answer (score 0):

In ext 7.5 you should add trigger to your field.

```
triggers: {
   clearTrigger: {
      cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
      handler: function() {
          //function to clean field
      }
   }
}
```